# Access 2010 filter by form adding extra fields to query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

We just upgraded our office from Office 2007 to Office 2010.

We have an internal Access database that we use pretty frequently. Several of our users use the Filter by Form functionality often.

Ever since we upgraded to Office 2010, they have not been able to use the Filter by Form feature.

If I click on Home->Advanced(in the Sort & Filter section)->Clear all Filters, and then click Home->Advanced->Filter By Form, and populate any field on the entire form with whatever I want to filter by, and then I hit Toggle Filter.

I get a blank form back, and with an ID of (New). If I try to move forward or backward a record, I get an error that says "You can't go to the specified record."

So, I went to Home->Advanced->Advanced Filter/Sort, and this loaded a query. The query looks correct, but there is an additional Field, named 0, with a Criteria of "<>False And <>False And <>False And <>False". If I delete this extra Field, and hit Toggle Filter, the filter works correctly.

This is happening consistently on all 5 computers in the office, and on any form in the database. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jeremiah

Comment: Interesting similar to:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487180/access-2003-form-filter-not-working-after-installing-office-2010

Comment: I ran across that earlier, before I posted my question, and I thought it might be the answer. But I tried the steps and it didn't work. I actually completely uninstalled and reinstalled office 2010 and A2003 runtime. Also, I am not using VBA, the users are actually clicking on the Filter/Sort button in the Access menu.

Comment: Is this with one form in particular, or all of them?  If only one, then you could rebuild that form from scratch.

Comment: It is happening to all of the forms.

Comment: How weird.  Does it happen on every database, even one newly created?  If does, that's weird cubed.

Comment: Show us the SQL view of your strange query.

Answer (score 0):

A search on "Access 'field named zero' OR 'field named 0'" turns up a few experiences that are conceivably related to yours.

Decompiling is a trouble shooting step that can always be recommended, and fixes all sorts of oddities.  See http://www.groupacg.com/ACodeTip.htm#DECOMP.

Comment: How does decompiling the VBA project have an effect on data-related properties of forms?

Comment: David, I don't know that it does.  And since you obviously think it doesn't, I am sure you are correct.  I have been surprised at the range of things it does fix, however.  I was hoping you would show up here to see what you think about the OP.

Comment: Decompile has no effect on anything but the compiled VBA code. Data properties of forms (or other objects of the Access project) are not effected in any way whatsoever.